# best way to find substring using regex in python 3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.7

I was trying to find out the best way to find the specific substring in key value pair using **re** for the following:

```
some_string-variable_length/some_no_variable_digit/some_no1_variable_digit/some_string1/some_string2
eg: aba/101/11111/cde/xyz or aaa/111/1119/cde/xzx or ada/21111/5/cxe/yyz
```

here everything is variable and what I was looking for is something like below in key value pair:

```
`cde: 2` as there are two entries for cde

cxe: 1 as there is only one cxe
```

Note: everything is variable here except **/**. ie cde or cxe or some string will be there exactly after two **/** in each case

```
input:aba/101/11111/cde/xyz/blabla
output: cde:xyz/blabla
input: aaa/111/1119/cde/xzx/blabla
output: cde:xzx/blabla
input: aahjdsga/11231/1119/gfts/sjhgdshg/blabla
output: gfts:sjhgdshg/blabla
```

If you notice here, my key is always the first string after 3rd **/** and value is always the substring after key

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you're trying to achieve. Could you please [edit] your post with specific input data and the expected output from that?

Comment: updated input and output example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of solutions based on your description that "key is always the first string after 3rd / and value is always the substring after key". The first uses [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with a `maxsplit` of 4 to collect everything after the fourth `/` into the value. The second uses regex to extract the two parts:

```
inp = ['aba/101/11111/cde/xyz/blabla',
        'aaa/111/1119/cde/xzx/blabla',
        'aahjdsga/11231/1119/gfts/sjhgdshg/blabla'
        ]

for s in inp:
    parts = s.split('/', 4)
    key = parts[3]
    value = parts[4]
    print(f'{key}:{value}')

import re

for s in inp:
    m = re.match(r'^(?:[^/]*/){3}([^/]*)/(.*)$', s)
    if m is not None:
        key = m.group(1)
        value = m.group(2)
        print(f'{key}:{value}')
```

For both pieces of code the output is

```
cde:xyz/blabla
cde:xzx/blabla
gfts:sjhgdshg/blabla
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for using re. Now, if I want to tweak it a bit to have key value pair as cde:2(2 entries of cde, ie count) and gfts:1 (only one entry of gfts). Can we do that?

Comment: @Jacob you could push the key values to a list and use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count them e.g. https://ideone.com/7Ip5uo

Comment: looks like it's giving count based on nno of cde or gfts appearing in there. What I was looking was how many xzx in cde(say count1) and how many xyz in cde(count2) and total = addition of both(count1+count2) so that I can see count 1 coming from first and count2 coming for second and so on.....Is that even possible by regex library?

Comment: @Jacob I think this has gone beyond the ability of comments to properly describe the problem. You should ask a new question and include more details as to exactly what output you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try `(?<!\S)[^\s/]*(?:/[^\s/]*){2}/([^\s/]*)`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8eeOS/1)

---

Try new per commnt

`(?<!\S)[^\s/]*(?:/[^\s/]*){2}/([^\s/]*)(?:/(\S*))?`

[demo2](https://regex101.com/r/kexc74/1)

Comment: aderd updats anser

Answer (score 0):

Others have already posted various regexes; a more broad question — is this problem best solved using a regex? Depending on how the data is formatted overall, it may be better parsed using

- the `.split('/')` [method on the string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split); or
- `csv.reader(..., delimiter='/')` or `csv.DictReader(..., delimiter='/')` in the [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module.